# How can I interpret relative and absolute income of both partners in one regression?

Tags: regression, linear-model, regression-coefficients, confounding

Suppose you want to examine the effect of income on the amount of housework for women. Does it make sense to include both relative income (compared to partners income) and absolute income of BOTH partners in a linear regression? The question is if relative or absolute income is more important for the amount of housework. Simple regression equation could look like that:

$ Amount \ of \ Housework \ (hours/week)=$ $\beta_1\times Income$_$Share+\beta_2 \times personal$_$income + \beta_3 \times partners\_income$

where $Income\_Share = personal\_income / (personal\_income+partners\_income)$

How do I interpret the coefficients? $\beta_1$ would be the effect of income share on housework holding personal and partner's income constant. But if I hold them constant, the income share should be constant, too, and cannot increase by one unit, right?

But, why is there no problem of collinearity if I include all three variables?

Comment: *personal_income = total_income * income_share*, so its an interaction, thats why there is no strict colinearity. Is *Amount of housework* a total (in hours, say) or a proportion? Please give better variable definitions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I didn't see the interaction. Yes, amount of housework is measured in hours /week.